# Big picture question about the Thurston Metric on Teichmüller Space

Tags: soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmueller-theory

I'm having difficulty in appreciating the significance of the Thurston metric on Teichmüller space. It seems like a lot of work to develop the theory of this asymmetric metric space with fewer significant results than you would hope.

So what's the big deal about the Thurston metric? What are the most useful things that it does for you? What makes it so significant?
Any insight would be fabulous.

Comment: How many (and what kind of) significant results did you hope for?

Comment: Mostly something that justifies the study of the Thurston metric. What kind of results can you get from it? Can well known, but important, results be reproved using it? 

To be honest I'm studying the lipschitz metric on outer space and I'm trying to understand the excitement around it. It's a close analog of the Thurston metric, so what are people expecting to get out of it?

Comment: My guess is that in Thurston's metric is interesting since it interacts directly with hyperbolic geometry, unlike Teichmuller's metric. I do not know much about the outer space, but my understanding is that it does not have any other natural metrics. Maybe this one will provide some further insight into $Out(F_n)$. You should probably ask your advisor.